# Can i use PFX/PKCS12 file for java key store directly?

Tags: java, ssl, pfx, pkcs#12

This is more of a practice question, i've read everywhere questions and articles on how to convert/import stuff from PKCS12 file onto java keystore, but if i want to use it for SSL server certificates, and given that java supports reading PKCS12 files, and that i can create a pfx file (which is PCKS12) from windows certmgr.msc, is there any reason why i shouldn't use the exported pfx file directly in java without any conversion?

Comment: **For keystore** (i.e. privatekey + cert chain for yourself) **yes**. For _truststore_ Java since j8 supports PKCS12 format but the certbag item(s) must have a special Oracle-defined attribute included which Windows certmgr won't do (nor will OpenSSL commandline).

Comment: thanks, i'm trying to figure out the most streamlined way to import with certificate replies and trust chain (from intranet sites) without using keytool